# Regular expression in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a URL like below.

```
/shows/the-ruby-book/meta-programming/?play=5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db"
```

I need to extract only the id of the play (i.e. `5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db`) using regular expression. How can I do it?

Comment: Notice that, sometimes, you will miss answers with the best solutions because of unnecessary constraints being added to the problem. In this case, that is to use regular expression. In other words, your question is an XY-problem.

Comment: See? (Cf. spickermann's answer)

Comment: Don't use regular expressions for this. Use the existing tools like URI or Addressable::URI.

Comment: Why are asking us how to use a hammer to solve your problem, when other (better!) tools exist?

Comment: rubyist, if you're not familiar with the expression "XY problem", [here's](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use a regexp to parse a url. I would use Ruby's libraries to handle URLs:

```
require 'uri'

url = '/shows/the-ruby-book/meta-programming/?play=5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db'

uri = URI.parse(url)
params = URI::decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h

params['play']
# => 5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db
```

Comment: You should use [`URI::decode_www_form`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-decode_www_form) rather than bother with CGI.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
str = '/shows/the-ruby-book/meta-programming/?play=5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db'
match = str.match(/.*\?play=([^&]+)/)
puts match[1]

=> "5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db"
```

The regex `/.*\?play=([^&]+)/` will match everything up until `?play=`, and then capture anything that is not a `&` (the query string parameter separator)

A match will create a `MatchData` object, represented here by `match` variable, and captures will be indices of the object, hence your matched data is available at `match[1]`.

Comment: I think this could be simplified to `str[/(?<=\?play=)[^&]+/]`, but I don't understand why `[^&]+`, rather than just `.+`, is needed. Please explain the role of `&`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland ...Seriously? Isn't it a query string separator? Isn't it also already explained in the answer? Also, would be good if you could  explain _why_ your version is actually any simpler.

Comment: I'm a Ruby hobbiest who knows nothing of markup (strange as that may seem). That's why I don't know what a query string separator is. I used the term "simplified" because I thought my suggestion saved a step. I now see it doesn't, as you didn't have to have to use the local variable `match`.

Answer (score 1):

```
url = '/shows/the-ruby-book/meta-programming/?play=5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db'
url.split("play=")[1] #=> "5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db"
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby's built-in [URI](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) class has everything needed to correctly parse, split and decode URLs:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('/shows/the-ruby-book/meta-programming/?play=5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db')
URI::decode_www_form(uri.query).to_h['play'] # => "5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db"
```

If you're using an older Ruby that doesn't support `to_h`, use:

```
Hash[URI::decode_www_form(uri.query)]['play'] # => "5b35a825-d372-4375-b2f0-f641a38067db"
```

You should use URI, rather than try to split/extract using a regexp, because the query of a URI will be encoded if any values are not within the characters allowed by the spec. URI, or [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable), will decode those back to their original values for you.